# Cannot mount external hard drive on Windows and Linux

Tags: external-hard-drive

My brother has a problem with his external hard drive (Western Digital 500 GB, NTFS file system), he can't read the stuff on it with his Windows 7 PC, however I think Windows recognizes it as he is adviced to format it.

I told him I will show him the power of Linux (backtrack 5) and get his data back before we format it. The thing is, I have been trying since for a week and I think I'm not going anywhere.

This is what I get in `/var/log/messages` when I plug it in:

```
Jun 10 15:45:34 bt kernel: [15909.210843] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:45:35 bt kernel: [15910.061906] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jun 10 15:45:35 bt kernel: [15910.069601] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
Jun 10 15:45:35 bt kernel: [15910.069792] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
Jun 10 15:45:35 bt kernel: [15910.069943] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jun 10 15:45:35 bt kernel: [15910.069945] USB Mass Storage support registered.
Jun 10 15:45:37 bt kernel: [15912.024089] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0730 1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun 10 15:45:37 bt kernel: [15912.025002] scsi 6:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun 10 15:45:37 bt kernel: [15912.029003] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun 10 15:45:37 bt kernel: [15912.031516] scsi 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
Jun 10 15:45:39 bt kernel: [15914.290239] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 976707584 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
Jun 10 15:45:39 bt kernel: [15914.290803] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jun 10 15:45:39 bt kernel: [15914.305408]  sdb: sdb1
Jun 10 15:45:39 bt kernel: [15914.307733] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jun 10 15:45:39 bt kernel: [15914.434383] ses 6:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
Jun 10 15:45:45 bt kernel: [15920.162614] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:45:51 bt kernel: [15926.699493] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:45:58 bt kernel: [15933.236403] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:04 bt kernel: [15939.797082] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:11 bt kernel: [15946.333884] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:18 bt kernel: [15952.870834] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:18 bt kernel: [15953.618978] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Jun 10 15:46:18 bt kernel: [15953.618988] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 10 15:46:18 bt kernel: [15953.618996] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 08 08 00 00 08 00
Jun 10 15:46:24 bt kernel: [15959.407728] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:31 bt kernel: [15965.956325] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:37 bt kernel: [15972.493248] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:44 bt kernel: [15979.029990] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:50 bt kernel: [15985.566913] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:57 bt kernel: [15992.107636] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:46:58 bt kernel: [15992.855867] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Jun 10 15:46:58 bt kernel: [15992.855876] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 10 15:46:58 bt kernel: [15992.855885] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 08 08 00 00 08 00
Jun 10 15:47:03 bt kernel: [15998.688559] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Jun 10 15:47:10 bt kernel: [16005.237293] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
```

And it continues reset again and again.

Could you help me?

Comment: Windows 7 can't read the data on the drive.  Windows 7 just suggests formatting it.  Linux can't read the data on the drive.  Sounds like the drive is dead.  I'm willing to bet that if you tried to format it, the format process would fail.

Comment: Or maybe USB board is fried... HDD may (or may not) work if connected directly to SATA. At least with my experience it is more than often worth to try, some drives (broken ones) seem to work better when connected to real SATA. I think it has something to do with better interface reset/recovery from error. Also if drive is broken but is recognized with SATA try to read it backwards...